# TCP/IP - Send HEX packets in C/C++ to control a relay board

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, tcp, tcpclient

I have an electronics board which has 16 relays and it works over TCP/IP.
The IP address of the board is 192.168.1.4 and the port is 3000.
I would like to control it with C/C++ under Ubuntu.

There is a list of HEX commands that it is possible to use in order to remotely switch ON and OFF each relay on the board.
This is the list:

```
    "580112000000016C",  // switch on the relay 1
    "580111000000016B",  // switch off the relay 1
    "580112000000026D",  // switch on the relay 2
    "580111000000026C",  // switch off the relay 2
    "580112000000036E",  // and so on..
```

I'm correctly able to switch on and off each relay by sending command line commands under Ubuntu:

```
echo '580112000000016C' | xxd -r -p | nc 192.168.1.4 3000
```

The above code correctly turns on the relay.

I would like to do the same with C/C++ code since I want to control the board from a WxWidgets application.
For the moment, I'm starting from base and I'm just using C/C++ code in order to test the tcp connection.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char sendline[1000];
    char recvline[1000];

    std::string serveraddr = "192.168.1.4";

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serveraddr.c_str());
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(3000);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    int number = 0x580112000000016C;

    int sendsize;
    sendsize = snprintf(sendline, sizeof(sendline), "%x", number);

    send(sockfd, sendline, sendsize * sizeof(char), 0);

}
```

How should I send the HEX commands?
When I compile this code I get this warning:

```
g++ tcp.c -o tcp tcp.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
tcp.c:29:18: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     int number = 0x580112000000016C;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and obviously the program doesn't work.

Can you help me please? I'm a beginner and I'm not understanding how to correctly send the HEX instructions.

EDIT1
This is the code after the suggestion of Nielsen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char sendline[1000];
    char recvline[1000];

    std::string serveraddr = "192.168.1.4";

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serveraddr.c_str());
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(3000);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    //int number = 0x580112000000016C;
    //uint8_t buffer[] = { 0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x6C};
   const char *command = "580112000000016C\n";

int bytes_to_send = strlen(command);
int bytes_sent = 0;

while(bytes_sent < bytes_to_send) {
    n = send(sockfd, command + bytes_sent, bytes_to_send - bytes_sent, 0);
    if ( n < 0 ) {
        printf("Error!\n"); break;
    }
    bytes_sent += n;
}
}
```

However, it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Always check the return values. The calls to `socket` and `connect` can fail outright and `send` can't always do exactly what you want, but will tell you what it did.

Comment: I updated the code in my first post to reflect the Nielsen suggestions; unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I removed the warning problem as you suggested. The port is 3000, there was a typo in the pasted code. I corrected it in the main post.

Comment: My question was "how to send the instruction via TCP/IP", I got no fail during the compilation because my code compiles correctly but it doesn't work. The warning was just a side effect of the suggestions generated during the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell command `xxd -r -p` takes a hex string as input and decodes it to raw binary for output.

`echo '580112000000016C'` outputs the hex string, which `xxd` then decodes and outputs as binary, which `nc` then sends.

You are not sending the raw binary in your socket code, you are sending the hex string.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    std::string serveraddr = "192.168.1.4";

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( sockfd < 0 )
    {
        cerr << "Error creating socket! " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serveraddr.c_str());
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(3000);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error connecting socket!" << strerror(errno) << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x6C}; // switch on the relay 1
    //uint8_t command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x6B}; // switch off the relay1
    //uint8_t command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x6D}; // switch on the relay 2
    //uint8_t command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x6C}; // switch off the relay 2
    //uint8_t command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x6E}; // and so on..

    int bytes_to_send = sizeof(command);
    int bytes_sent = 0;

    do
    {
        n = send(sockfd, command + bytes_sent, bytes_to_send - bytes_sent, 0);
        if ( n < 0 )
        {
            cerr << "Error writing to socket!" << strerror(errno) << endl;
            close(sockfd);
            return 1;
        }
        bytes_sent += n;
    }
    while (bytes_sent < bytes_to_send);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, you are my hero and my master! :) It works fine!

Comment: Just a question: command contains HEX data, so when the hex information is converted to binary in your example?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet there is no conversion. Remy  provides the command in binary directly with `uint8_t command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x6C};`

Comment: Thank you! I got it

Answer (score 6):

This

```
const char *command = "580112000000016C\n";
```

won't work as-is, because that's an ASCII string (or whatever character set your local implementation uses) and you need to parse it to get the numeric form: you're missing the equivalent of the `xxd` step of your original pipeline. (You should also remove the trailing `\n` unless you actually want to send it on the wire, but that's not the main problem here).

Next, *this*

```
int number = 0x580112000000016C;
```

won't work unless that literal fits in your platform's `int`. Since that's usually 32 bits, you can't fit a 64-bit number in there.

Fixing the variable size with

```
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t number = 0x580112000000016Cull;
```

will probably work, but now you have a new problem: the actual octet sequence this value sends to the network depends on your platform's byte ordering.

This one

```
uint8_t buffer[] = { 0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x6C};
```

really should work: at least, the octet values are correct and you know they're in the right order.

If you strongly prefer *writing* the first (string) form, then this is the output the string should convert to.

---

Quick comment on methodology:

You have a shell pipeline that works. That means you can write a server pipeline using `nc -l` to see exactly what your C++ program actually sent, for comparison. Do that.

It also means you could start by writing your program to *only* replace the `nc` stage of the pipeline: this lets you confirm the network code works correctly in isolation.

When I say you could convert the string form into the octet array form, I mean: first get the octet array working. Then, write a function to convert the string form into an octet array, and *finally* test that the output of that function is identical.

If you notice a pattern in the methodology, it is hopefully to *always* break problems down into smaller sub-problems. If you write a program and find you're not sure whether your bug lies in the network code, or the string formatting or the buffer manipulation, then you wrote too much code at once and waited too long to test it.

Comment: I already tried to use the buffer solution without success.
`char buffer[] ="580112000000016C";
    int sendsize;
    sendsize = snprintf(sendline, sizeof(sendline), "%s", buffer);

    send(sockfd, sendline, sendsize * sizeof(char), 0); `

Comment: @MarcusBarnet yo are sending symbols '5' '8' '0' '1' '1' and so on, in your case you send ASCII codes of each symbol. Instead you need to send bytes `0x58` then `0x01` thex `0x12` ans so on. You method with `int` does not work due to endianess - you send your bytes but in wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says, the `int` type is not large enough to hold the data. You should use an `unsigned long long` or `#include<stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t`. However, it is easiest just to define the data directly `const char command[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x6C};`.

Also you should check the return value of `send()` to verify all data was sent.

Update - using `send()`:

```
int bytes_to_send = sizeof(command)/sizeof(command[0]);
int bytes_sent = 0;
int n;
while(bytes_sent < bytes_to_send) {
    n = send(sockfd, command + bytes_sent, bytes_to_send - bytes_sent, 0);
    if ( n < 0 ) {
        printf("Error!\n"); break;
    }
    bytes_sent += n;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested: `char *command = "580112000000016C";
    int sendsize;
    sendsize = snprintf(sendline, sizeof(sendline), "%s", command);

    send(sockfd, sendline, sendsize * sizeof(char), 0);` but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet you do not need `snprintf` you already have the string. And you cannot expect that `send()` would send all data at once.

Comment: What do you mean, @Slava? can't I use send() as I'm doing it now?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet `send()` may not send all bytes at once. The return value is `-1` on failure or the number of bytes sent. Not all bytes are necessarily sent at once, so you may need to call `send()` again with the remaining bytes. I have updated the answer to show the principle.

Comment: Thank you, Nielsen, unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I updated my first post with the new code and the warning that I get during the compilation with g++.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Right, you need to make `command` a const, i.e. `const char *command = ...`.

Comment: Yes, i did it but still nothing

Comment: @MarcusBarnet you are trying to send the hex string itself, but you need to instead send the binary data that the hex string represents.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have edited the answer to reflect that binary data must be sent, I do not know how I missed that in the first place. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @nielsen `strlen()` is the wrong way to get the byte count of binary data